# Android Wear : How to receive Simple Data from Other Wear Apps?

Tags: android-intent, share, wear-os

I want to receive simple data to my Android wear app from other android wear apps. That is, I want to list my application when user clicks on share icon in other wear apps.

For android phone app it works fine with code below. 
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

But this technique is not working in the Android Wear app.

Below is the Android manifest I have written for the same.

```xml
<activity
    android:name="com.test.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But the share option on Wear apps is not listing my app. 
Is there any way to do the same? Kindly please suggest.

Comment: Do you have an example of an app initiating a share? It may be worth investigating that end of things, whether it's being done with a standard broadcast Intent.